# Violin plot smooth edges

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

A general question without code: violin plots in R seems to have rough/pixelareted edges and not really smooth like in the example. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using `ggsave()` to save the chart? If so, it could just be a question of playing with the `dpi` argument to increase the image resolution.

Comment: Ha oke well ggsave() did the trick...previously I saved it manually...this worked thx!!